# What are uniqueness checks for an UnsafeBufferPointer?

Tags: swift

In the `UnsafeBufferPointer` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafebufferpointer), it reads "You can use an `UnsafeBufferPointer` instance in low level operations to eliminate uniqueness checks and, in release mode, bounds checks."

I understand that a bounds check is checking that your index is within the bounds of the collection (i.e., 0 <= i < length), but what is a uniqueness check in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you modify a value type that has copy-on-write (such as `Array`), there is a check that the current reference is unique (see `isKnownUniquelyReferenced`). If it is uniquely referenced, then no copy is required and the mutation can happen directly on the buffer. This uniqueness check (may) happen every time you modify the array:

```
var array = [1,2,3]

array[0] = 2 // Check for uniqueness
array[1] = 3 // Check for uniqueness
array[2] = 4 // Check for uniqueness
```

I believe the optimizer can eliminate these checks in some cases (actually I think it does it for a lot of cases), so this may not always happen, but the optimizer can't always pull that off.

In cases where the optimizer can't figure it out, an unsafe buffer can. For example:

```
array.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { (ptr) -> Void in
    ptr[0] = 3
    ptr[1] = 4
    ptr[2] = 5
}
```

The call to `withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer` will perform a uniqueness check and create a copy if necessary, but each reference to `ptr[x]` will not re-check uniqueness.

This should not be taken as a suggestion to use `withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer` "for performance." Write the code simply, let the optimizer do its job, and profile. But in some cases, the performance benefits may be worthwhile.

BTW, I'm not aware of any cases where this uniqueness check would matter for the immutable buffer (`UnsafeBufferPointer`). I believe it only really applies to `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer`. But both of these types are defined in the same [`gyb` file](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/UnsafeBufferPointer.swift.gyb) and get the same overview documentation.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks!